# VB.net if else convert to case select

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

hi guys can you help me to convert this to case select statement, this is my first time using case select statement.

```
If TabControl1.SelectedTab Is tp_5 Then
      myqry = "SELECT * FROM TBLVLAN5 ORDER BY ID"
ElseIf TabControl1.SelectedTab Is tp_7 Then
      myqry = "SELECT * FROM TBLVLAN7 ORDER BY ID"
```

i search in web but i only found case select statement using integer and string and not the one that fit with my if else example.

i also try use it but its not working, this is my code.

```
Dim h As String
    h = TabControl1.SelectedTab Is tp_10
    Select Case h
        Case TabControl1.SelectedTab Is tp_5
            myqry = "SELECT * FROM TBLVLAN5 ORDER BY ID"
        Case TabControl1.SelectedTab Is tp_7
            myqry = "SELECT * FROM TBLVLAN7 ORDER BY ID"
        Case TabControl1.SelectedTab Is tp_8
            myqry = "SELECT * FROM TBLVLAN8 ORDER BY ID"
    End Select
```

any help is greatly appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: Set Option Strict to ON. `Dim h As String` is incorrect because `Is tp_10` returns a `Boolean`.

Comment: Why wont you just use the "SelectedIndex" or the "SelectedTab.Name" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is as follows:

```
Select Case True
    Case TabControl1.SelectedTab Is tp_5
        myqry = "SELECT * FROM TBLVLAN5 ORDER BY ID"
    Case TabControl1.SelectedTab Is tp_7
        myqry = "SELECT * FROM TBLVLAN7 ORDER BY ID"
End Select
```

It's up to you to decide if this is more readable than the `If..Then..Else` :)

Comment: What an abuse of the `Select Case`.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a `Select...Case` to compare references with `Is`, use the `If...Else`:

```
If TabControl1.SelectedTab Is tp_5 Then
      myqry = "SELECT * FROM TBLVLAN5 ORDER BY ID"
ElseIf TabControl1.SelectedTab Is tp_7 Then
      myqry = "SELECT * FROM TBLVLAN7 ORDER BY ID"  
...
End If
```

As an aside, i warmly recommend to set `Option Strict` to `ON`.

`Dim h As String` doesn't compile then because  because `Is tp_10` returns a `Boolean`. `Option Strict` prevents you from incorrect magic compiler conversions that aren't desired.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the need for an If or a Case statement.

If you set the name property of the tabs to something like "tab_5", you could set myqry string by:

```
myqry = "SELECT * FROM TBLVLAN" + TabControl1.SelectedTab.Name.Split("_")[1] + " ORDER BY ID"
```

This would take the number part of the Tab name and put it in the sql query string.